# Pandas dataframe: Extracting float values from string in a column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to extract a floating value from a string for a particular column.

Original Output

```
DATE        strCondition
4/3/2018    2.9
4/3/2018    3.1, text
4/3/2018    2.6 text
4/3/2018    text, 2.7
```

and other variations.
I've also tried regex but my knowledge here is limited, I've come up with:

```
clean = df['strCondition'].str.contains('\d+km')
df['strCondition'] = df['strCondition'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand = False).astype(float)
```

where the output ends up looking like this where it displays the main integer shown...

```
DATE        strCondition
4/3/2018    2.0
4/3/2018    3.0
4/3/2018    2.0
4/3/2018    2.0
```

My desired output would be along the lines of:

```
DATE        strCondition
4/3/2018    2.9
4/3/2018    3.1
4/3/2018    2.6
4/3/2018    2.7
```

I appreciate your time and inputs!

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that in my original dataframe there are strCondition entries similar to

```
2.9(1.0) #where I would like both numbers to get returned
11/11/2018 #where this date as a string object can be discarded
```

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: `\d+km` doesn't match anything in the string.

Comment: Try `df['float'] = df['strCondition'].str.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?').apply(', '.join)`

Comment: To avoid matching digits in dates you may use `df['float'] = df['strCondition'].str.findall(r'\b(?<!\d/)\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b(?!/\d)').apply(', '.join)`. Does it work like expected now?

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
df['float'] = df['strCondition'].str.extract(r'(\d+.\d+)').astype('float')
```

Output:

```
       DATE strCondition  float
0  4/3/2018          2.9    2.9
1  4/3/2018    3.1, text    3.1
2  4/3/2018     2.6 text    2.6
3  4/3/2018    text, 2.7    2.7
```

Comment: So, you want the first float and not the ones inside parenthesis?

Comment: Ideally it would be cool to have it spit out both float values, even the one inside parenthesis. 

If we can only return only the float outside of the parenthesis that is a good solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

A simple replace would be

Find `(?m)^([\d/]+[ \t]+).*?(\d+\.\d+).*`

Replace `\1\2`

https://regex101.com/r/pVC4jc/1

Comment: That does work for some of the strings, but what about the dates as a string in my original data?

Comment: @JQJQ - when a determination is made on the complete sample text  expected to match and what it will look like after substituted, then a complete solution can be made.

Answer (score 0):

In case you also want to convert negative numbers with a minus sign at the beginning, this should do it:

```
df['strCondition'] = df['strCondition'].str.extract('(-{0,1}\d+\.\d+)', expand=False).astype(float)
```